# Phone mask for text field with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mask

I'm using this function to phone mask and works almost perfectly.

```
function mask(o, f) 
{ 
    v_obj = o; 
    v_fun = f; 
    setTimeout("execmask()", 1) 
};

function execmask() 
{ 
    v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value) 
};

function mphone(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");           
    v=v.substring(0, 11);
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"(OXX$1) $2"); 
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2"); 
    return v;
}
```

Here I run the mask in the text field:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onkeypress="mask(this, mphone);" onblur="mask(this, mphone);" />
```

The problem is that I need to change this part of the code `(OXX$1)` to `(0XX$1)`.

Current situation:

| No. Of Digits | Input Field |
| --- | --- |
| 9 digit | (OXX99) 99999-9999 |
| 8 digit | (OXX99) 9999-9999 |

The correct formatting that I need:

| No. Of Digits | Input Field |
| --- | --- |
| 9 digit | (0XX99) 99999-9999 |
| 8 digit | (0XX99) 9999-9999 |

The amount of 8 or 9 digits is the choice of the user.

Changing `O` to `0`, causes an error in the mask.

Comment: could not see the issue . http://jsfiddle.net/ufsuz/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function mask(o, f) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var v = f(o.value);
        if (v != o.value) {
            o.value = v;
        }
    }, 1);
}

function mphone(v) {
    var r = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    r = r.replace(/^0/,"");
    if (r.length > 10) {
        // 11+ digits. Format as 5+4.
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/,"(0XX$1) $2-$3");
    }
    else if (r.length > 5) {
        // 6..10 digits. Format as 4+4
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/,"(0XX$1) $2-$3");
    }
    else if (r.length > 2) {
        // 3..5 digits. Add (0XX..)
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/,"(0XX$1) $2");
    }
    else {
        // 0..2 digits. Just add (0XX
        r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "(0XX$1");
    }
    return r;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BBeWN/

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you!

But I forgot to specify a detail:

If the phone has 8 digits, the formatting should be like this:
(0XX99) 9999-9999

If the phone have 9 digits, looks like this:
(0XX99) 99999-9999

The amount of 8 or 9 digit is the choice of the user.

What should I change this function?

Grateful

Comment: I suggest to start using mask only after the first char, since we can clear the entire value. I also suggest to add the `-` only when `r.length > 6`, so deleting char by char (backspace) will keep this function working.

Answer (score 1):

In this project you can see the use of several methods below, including the phone mask and applying them to an input:

Repository: [react-text-field-mask](https://github.com/MarcosSantosDev/react-text-field-mask)

Demo sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-monad-qzod32

Regex masks:

```
// (00) 00000-0000
const phoneMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '($1) $2')
    .replace(/(\d{5})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2');
};

// (00) 0000-0000
const landlineTelephoneMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '($1) $2')
    .replace(/(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2');
};

// 10.000,00 -> 10000.00
const removeMoneyMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const originalNumber = Number(value);
  const numberIsWithMask = Number.isNaN(originalNumber);

  if (numberIsWithMask) {
    const stringValue = value.toString();
    const splitedMoneyMask = stringValue
      .split('.')
      .join('')
      .split(',')
      .join('.');

    return splitedMoneyMask.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, '');
  }

  return value.toString();
};

type BehaviorMode = 'standard' | 'typing';

const moneyMaskCustomization = {
  /**
   * typingMode - The value is typed from right to left:
   *  - '1' -> '0.01'
   *  - '10' -> '0.10'
   *
   * defaultMode - Simple conversion:
   *  - '1' -> '1.00'
   *  - '10' -> '10.00'
   */
  maskBehaviorMode: (behaviorMode: BehaviorMode, value: string | number) => {
    const numberWithoutMask = removeMoneyMask(value);
    const normalizedMoneyValue = moneyMaskCustomization.normalizeMoneyValue(
      numberWithoutMask.toString(),
    );
    const integerWithoutDecimalPlaces = normalizedMoneyValue.length === 1;

    if (behaviorMode === 'typing' && integerWithoutDecimalPlaces) {
      const newNumberFormat = Number(normalizedMoneyValue) / 100;
      return Number(newNumberFormat).toFixed(2);
    }

    if (behaviorMode === 'standard' && integerWithoutDecimalPlaces) {
      return Number(normalizedMoneyValue).toFixed(2);
    }

    return normalizedMoneyValue;
  },
  normalizeMoneyValue: (numberToNormalized: string) => {
    const [stringInteger, stringDecimal] = numberToNormalized.split('.');

    if (stringDecimal && stringDecimal.length === 1) {
      const lastPositionOfTheInteger = stringInteger.length - 1;
      const lastToIntegerPlace = stringInteger[lastPositionOfTheInteger];

      if (lastPositionOfTheInteger !== 0) {
        const firstIntegerPlace = stringInteger.substring(
          0,
          lastPositionOfTheInteger,
        );

        return `${firstIntegerPlace}.${lastToIntegerPlace}${stringDecimal}`;
      }

      return `${0}.${lastToIntegerPlace}${stringDecimal}`;
    }

    if (stringDecimal && stringDecimal.length === 3) {
      const firstDecimalPlace = stringDecimal.substring(0, 1);
      const lastTwoDecimalPlaces = stringDecimal.substring(1, 3);
      const integerIsZero = Number(stringInteger) === 0;

      if (integerIsZero) {
        return `${firstDecimalPlace}.${lastTwoDecimalPlaces}`;
      }

      return `${stringInteger}${firstDecimalPlace}.${lastTwoDecimalPlaces}`;
    }

    return numberToNormalized;
  },
};

// 10.000,00
const moneyMask = (
  value: string | number,
  maskBehaviorMode: BehaviorMode = 'standard',
) => {
  if (value || Number.isInteger(value)) {
    const moneyValue = moneyMaskCustomization.maskBehaviorMode(
      maskBehaviorMode,
      value,
    );

    return moneyValue
      .replace(/\D/g, '')
      .replace(/\D/g, '.')
      .replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/, '$1,$2')
      .replace(/(?=(\d{3})+(\D))\B/g, '.');
  }
  return '';
};

// 000.000.000-00
const cpfMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/(-\d{2})\d+?$/, '$1');
};

// 00.000.000/0000-000
const cnpjMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1/$2')
    .replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/, '$1-$2');
};

// 000.000.000-00 or 00.000.000/0000-000
const cpfOrCnpjMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  if (stringValue.length >= 15) {
    return cnpjMask(value);
  }
  return cpfMask(value);
};

// 00000-000
const cepMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{5})(\d{3})+?$/, '$1-$2');
};

// 00/00/0000
const dateMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue
    .replace(/\D/g, '')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2')
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2')
    .replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, '$1');
};

const onlyLettersMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue.replace(/[0-9!@#¨$%^&*)(+=._-]+/g, '');
};

const onlyNumbersMask = (value: string | number) => {
  const stringValue = value.toString();
  return stringValue.replace(/\D/g, '');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes:

1. I changed the event to keyup (besides the fact that keypress has been deprecated) because keypress always takes the string with one less character and to work I also needed onblur, something that doesn't happen with keyup. Code adjustments were needed to resolve this
2. and the issue of the "-", that when tried to remove it with backspace it kept always coming back.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/windmateus/7tae9wps/1/)

```js
  function mascaraFone(event) {
    var valor = document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'];
    var retorno = valor.replace(/\D/g, "");
    retorno = retorno.replace(/^0/, "");
    if (retorno.length > 10) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{5})(\d{4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 5) {
      if (retorno.length == 6 && event.code == "Backspace") { 
        // necessário pois senão o "-" fica sempre voltando ao dar backspace
        return; 
      } 
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{4})(\d{0,4}).*/, "($1) $2-$3");
    } else if (retorno.length > 2) {
      retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,5})/, "($1) $2");
    } else {
      if (retorno.length != 0) {
        retorno = retorno.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("telefone").attributes[0].ownerElement['value'] = retorno;
  }
```

```html
<input id="telefone" onkeyup="mascaraFone(event)" />
```

Answer (score -5):

I love this function and I use it all the time.  I've added 2 other masks if anyone needs them.  I understand that they don't directly answer  the question, but they are super useful.

```
//Social Security Number for USA
 function mssn(v) {
    var r = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    r = r.replace(/^0/,"");
    if (r.length > 9) {
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d{2})(\d{0,4}).*/,"$1-$2-$3");
        return r;
    }
    else if (r.length > 4) {
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d{2})(\d{0,4}).*/,"$1-$2-$3");
    }
    else if (r.length > 2) {
        r = r.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d{0,3})/,"$1-$2");
    }
    else {
        r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "$1");
    }
    return r;
}

//USA date
function mdate(v) {
   var r = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
   if (r.length > 4) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{2})(\d{0,4}).*/,"$1/$2/$3");
   }
   else if (r.length > 2) {
    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d{0,2})/,"$1/$2");
   }
   else if (r.length > 0){
         if (r > 12) {
           r = "";
         }
   }
   return r;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: true.  I just know that it's been really useful to me, and I didn't really know where to add these

Comment: @NicolasGiszpencn Maybe try writing a blog post about these functions to share?

Comment: I don't have a blog.  Is there a place in StackOverflow for my submission, which is basically an add-on to a previous [somewhat related] submission?