# Mask javascript variable value

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to mask my javascript variable value.Basically i am getting phone number fields value in variable and after getting it i want to mask it in some other format.

I have tried the [jquery Mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) but its mask the control's string format.But i want to mask the string into the variable.

Ex:

Let i have a phone string `"0000000000"` and i am storing it in a variable :-

```
var number ="0000000000"
```

and after that i want to mask it in other formats.Like-

1)    number = number.mask('000-0000');
2)    number = number.mask('(000) 000-0000');

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense... the amount of zeros is different.

Comment: No matter the amount of zeros in the example, I believe that the aim of the question is quite clear...

Comment: you can use this plugin for masking http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Seriously, why does @elclanrs comment gets any upvotes?  It is not constructuve at all... (Neither is mine, though, lol...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a similar question ([Javascript phone mask for text field with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802100/javascript-phone-mask-for-text-field-with-regex)).

You can do it using regular expressions (see the code working at http://jsfiddle.net/BBeWN/45/):

```
var value = '1234567';
var formatted = value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2');
```

Notice that each part of the regular expression that is wrapped within parenthesis, `(\d{3})` and `(\d{4})` in the example above, can then be referenced to build the formatted text string using `$1` and `$2` respectively.

If you have N parts of the regular expression wrapped within parenthesis, you would be able to reference them to build a formatted text string with `$1`, `$2`, ..., `$N` respectively.

So, for the other format you mention ((000) 000-0000), the code would be like this:

```
var formatted = value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*/, '($1) $2-$3');
```

You can find a great JavaScript regular expressions reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 9):

There is a javascript library that provides a solution for this problem:

https://github.com/the-darc/string-mask

And you don't need to create a new regular expression every time you change your mask(Format).

You can use it just like that:

```
var formatter = new StringMask("(000) 000-0000", { reverse: true });
var result = formatter.apply('123456789'); // (012) 345-6789
```

or

```
var formatter = new StringMask('#.##0,00', { reverse: true });
var result = formatter.apply('123456789'); // 1.234.567,89
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "mask" you may apply to a string of phone number digits of length 7 or 10 with an optional "+" to render it with dashes.

```
number.match(/^\+?([0-9]{3}){1,2}([0-9]{4})$/) || []).join('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package https://github.com/jsonmaur/coverup, which can return the masked string as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using jsuites plugin you can do that

A) HTML

```
<html>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<input data-mask='+44 0000 000 000'>

</html>
```

B) JAVASCRIPT

To get the parse a string into a variable

```
<script>
var test = jSuites.mask.run('123456789', '(000) 000-0000');
console.log(test);
</script>
```

Source: https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/javascript-mask

Answer (score -2):

---

Start Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
}
```

html for mask

```
<input id="seachPeople" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" class="phone_us">
```

Getting masked string

```
// your string
var phoneApi ='0000000000'     
var phone  = ('.phone_us').masked(phoneApi);
consoe.log(phone)
//exit -> (000) 000-0000
```

```html
<input id="seachPeople" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" class="phone_us">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
// your string that comes from somewhere could be from an API
const numberPhone = '1111111111';
const maskPgoneStriong = $('.phone_us').masked(numberPhone);
console.log(maskPgoneStriong);
alert(maskPgoneStriong)

</script>
```

look:
http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#getting-a-masked-value-programmatically

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

I believe what you are looking for you can find on the apple.com support page. Try to schedule a call and check out their phone input field. It adjusts presentation based on the number of digits you are entering. Looking at the source, (seems like its somewhere [here](https://getsupport.apple.com/build/js/component10djs0f.js)) this one has the keyup event for the field and looks like they are parsing on keyup.