# any no. of alphanumeric value by mask input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can add multiple alphanumeric characters. In regular expression we use `[a-zA-z0-9 ]+`, `+` signifies you can add atleast one alphanumeric. So, how I can achieve this through mask i.e. adding multiple alphanumeric characters.

I have tried the following:

`jQuery('.alphanumeric-field').mask('A')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mask javascript variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650197/mask-javascript-variable-value)

Comment: Are you using a third party plugin? If so which one? If not, how are you generating the .mask()?

Comment: I find it:  

$('.Address, .APT').mask('Z', {
    translation: {
      'Z': { pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$", optional: true, recursive: true}
    },
    maxlength: false
  });

Comment: how to mask input such that user can enter either 5 or 9 digit:

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Address, .APT').mask('Z', {
    translation: {
      'Z': { pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$", optional: true, recursive: true}
    },
    maxlength: false
  });
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.