# How can I add two hyphens in an RegEx expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a value that I will want to add two hyphens.

For example, if I receive:

*FN322KN*

I want to transform it to:

*FN-322-KN*

I am trying to use this solution ([Mask javascript variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650197/mask-javascript-variable-value)) and Im stuck here:

**CODE:**

var value = 'FN322KN';

var formatted = value.replace(/^(.{2})(.{5}).*/, '$1-$2');

**RESULT KO:**

*'FN-322KN'*

Can someone please tell me how I can add the second "-" ?

**UPDATE!!**

Both Mark Baijens and Buttered_Toast answers are correct. I have one more question though. What if the value comes like FN-322KN or F-N322-KN ? Like, out of format? Because if thats the case, then it adds one hifen where one already exists, making it "--".

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any logic to match this string `FN322KN` Like characters A-Z and digits?

Comment: Do you always want the hyphens after the first 2 characters and after the first 5 characters?

Comment: It seems like the OP wants the hyphen whenever a character of `A` to `Z` is followed by a digit ... `/[A-Z](?=\d)/g` ... and whenever a digit is followed by a character of `A` to `Z` ... `/\d(?=[A-Z])/g` ... which leads to either of following solutions ... `'FN322KN'.replace(/[A-Z](?=\d)/g, '$&-').replace(/\d(?=[A-Z])/g, '$&-');` ... `'FN322KN'.replace(/[A-Z](?=\d)|\d(?=[A-Z])/g, '$&-');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you always want the hyphens after the first 2 characters and after the first 5 characters you can change the regex easily to 3 groups.

```js
var value = 'FN322KN';
var formatted = value.replace(/^(.{2})(.{3})(.{2}).*/, '$1-$2-$3');
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score -1):

Going by the provided content you have, you could try this

```
(?=(.{5}|.{2})$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/JZVivU/1

```js
const regex = /(?=(.{5}|.{2})$)/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('(?=(.{5}|.{2})$)', 'gm')

const str = `FN322KN`;
const subst = `-`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```