# Is there a way to apply a mask on keydown? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, keydown

I have this mask:

```
$(".cep").mask("99999-999");
```

Nevertheless, when I hold a number key, like 1, it fills the input text really fast, in a way that the mask is ignored (Instead of "11111-111", it fills like "111111111"), and this is immeasurably atrocious and bug-prone when combined with events such as change or keydown.

Anyway, is there a way to apply the mask on keydown, so that the user can hold to death the button and be bound to it??

Here's the class on HTML:

```
<div class="input text col-sm-6 col-xs-6 required">
    <input name="data[Fornecedor][cep]" placeholder="* CEP" maxlength="20" type="text" id="FornecedorCep" required="required" class="cep">
</div>
```

Comment: `.cep` is the input field class?

Comment: @RederickDeathwill See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25367230/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: - *untested*

```
$('.cep').on('keydown keypress input blur', function(){
     $(this).mask("99999-999");
});
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I wanted. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally spit-balling here - I don't know what `mask()` actually is, if it's a plugin you might have to edit it, but you could set a very fast interval to apply it when they hit a key, and then kill the interval on keyup.

Something like this:

```
   var maskInterval = null;
   $('.cep').on('keydown', function()
   {
      maskInterval = setInterval(function()
      {
            // Do whatever it takes to apply the mask here
            $('.cep').mask();
      }, 25);
   }).on('keyup', function()
   {
      clearInterval(maskInterval);
   });
```