# Is it possible to style a HTML text input field as a password field?

Tags: html, css, input-field

I've got a form with a textbox on it. I have had to apply an input mask on the field as per client's requirements. Client now wants to obscure the input in the manner of a password input field. I've tried setting it as password input but the mask stops working, Is this possible or should I give up now?

Comment: you can fake one with onkeyup to replace whatever was typed with `*`, and store the previously entered text elsewhere.

Comment: Yes it is possible but your question doesn't make any sense..

Comment: Try checking out the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367230/masking-a-social-security-number-input you should be able to refactor that for your purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I found this:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/password-input-bullet-alternatives/

Which leads to this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/8WpNg/
using the `-webkit-text-security` property

Seems to work in Chrome, but not Firefox. Searching a bit further I found this article that seems to discuss a JavaScript solution to making this degrade gracefully across browsers that do not support this feature with CSS: [Degrading -webkit-text-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822548/degrading-webkit-text-security)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for that @MikeMcCaughan, it's my first time answering on SO, will endeavour to do better in future. That's a fair point raised

Comment: Thanks @PhilGibbins. unfortunately I need a fully cross-browser solution so although this works perfectly on webkit based browsers it doesn't on IE which unfortunately I'm still writing for.